# AVD - Android doesn't care about set orientation

Tags: android, landscape

Hello I set the orientation to Landscape(by Eclipse icon flip orientation), but when i run the app the orientation is still standard(in Eclipse it is shown properly as landscape). Why is it so?

[image]

Comment: the icon only works for you to see how it would be displayed not to set the actual orientation on a real device. for that you have to set the parameter in your layout or manifest depending on what you want.

Comment: if what you want is to be compatible with both orientations but run/change the orientation when you are running the app you can do as @Sam says, press Ctrl+F11 and the emulator should rotate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest file, under the activity tag, write

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

This should set the orientation to landscape for good.